# ExoPlayer stuttering with url from a specific site

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So, my app plays radio stations from the Internet. And all is fine except of playing radio stations from 101.ru. Music is stuttering and I can't say that there are any equal time intervals between stutters.
I'm using ExoPlayer library v2.8.0.

**What have I tried to fix it:**

- To update ExoPlayer to 2.10.3 - no result
- To experiment with the buffer size of Exoplayer - no result or worst (few hours of experiments)

**My code of ExoPlayer init:**

```
IcyHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new IcyHttpDataSourceFactory.Builder(Util.getUserAgent(context, userAgent))
            .setIcyHeadersListener(this)
            .setIcyMetadataChangeListener(this).build();
dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, null, factory);

RenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(context);
TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(new DefaultBandwidthMeter());
DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector, loadControl);
player.addListener(this);
```

**My code of ExoPlayer play from url:**

```
player.prepare(generateMediaSource(Uri.parse(url)));

private MediaSource generateMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .setExtractorsFactory(new DefaultExtractorsFactory())
            .createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

So, 101.ru has about 80 radio stations and about 95% of them are stuttering. However, other 100-200 radio stations have an excellent quality.
What can I do to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue have been resolved. Problem was in IcyHttpDataSourceFactory. I've [wrote](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6227) in exoplayer github issues and there I've got an answer:

Version should be 2.10.3 and you shouldn't to use any other `IcyHttpDataSourceFactory` because they added ICY support in the latest release.

So, stuttering was resolved and sound is clear now.